# How to serialize and deserialize in android?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-studio

my mainActivity has a ListView which should display my CustomList:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomList implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Game> list = new ArrayList<Game>();
    public void add(Game toAdd){
        list.add(toAdd);
    }
    public Game get(int id){
        return list.get(id);
    }
    public ArrayList<Game> getList(){
        return list;
    }
    public void serialize(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("res\\data.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream ou = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            ou.writeObject(list);
            ou.close();
            fo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void deserialize(){
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("res\\data.dat");
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            list = (ArrayList<Game>)oi.readObject();
            oi.close();
            fi.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error trying to serialize or desirialize:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\data.dat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My question is how to proper point to my data.dat file.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write into the res directory (that's read-only), you have to write to somewhere else, e.g. to the cache directory (if it's only temporary; use [context.getCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) to get it's location) or to some permanent space (e.g. [context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())).

You can get the file location like this, what you can pass to the FileOutputStream's or the FileInputStream's constructor:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "data.dat");
```

You may also have to request permission to write to external storage if you choose so.

Read more about storing files in Android here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: What is "context"?