# How to put in memory a ListView and access it when the app is started again?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView with custom objects and I don't know how to keep its items in memory, so every time the app is open the ListView will have its items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize and deserialize in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054035/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SharedPreferences for this. For example:

```
public void storeListValues(String values) {
    // First retrieve the SharedPreferences    
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(FILL_IN_YOUR_APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // And put your values into memory
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("listValues", values).apply();
}
```

You'd have to convert the items into a String somehow, for example using comma separation.